# How to override the style of an element which has a class style definition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to use a class to change the display style of all elements of that class.  Then override the display style of individual elements which have that class.

The goal is to allow the user to display elements.  The script should hide all other elements and then display the desired elements.

I am able to override the display style once.  However, I can't do it a second time.  Though my DOM inspector says the element has display: inline-block, and the element is properly displayed, my function thinks the display is still set to none.  I used an alert to report back the display state.

I am using window.getComputedStyle to reference the computed style and not the stylesheet declaration.

I am using jquery-1.12.1 .

```js
function showhide(sent) {

  /* Hide all elements with class classy. */

  $(".classy").css({
    display: "none"
  });

  /* Grab target elemenet to show or hide. */

  var target_element = document.getElementById(sent);

  /* Get display style of target element. */

  true_value = window.getComputedStyle(target_element).getPropertyValue("display");

  /* Alert display state. */

  alert(true_value);

  /* If display state of traget element is none, change it to inline block. */

  if (true_value == "none") {
    target_element.style.display = "inline-block";
  }

  /* If display state of target element is inline-block change it to none. */

  if (true_value == "inline-block") {
    target_element.style.display = "none";
  }

  /* End of function. */
}
```

```css
.classy {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="click_thing" onclick="showhide('first_section')">
  Click This Please
</section>

<section id="first_section" class="classy">
  Some stuff here.
</section>
```

Comment: why are you not just adding another class to those elements? which than you can set the style with specificity?

Comment: My thinking was to use the bare minimum of classes.  I thought I could set the element's css directly while keeping it in the general class.  So it has all the properties of the class I want, and simply has its own display setting.  Then I can have multiple elements in the class displayed, but have them all hide with one line of code altering the class css.

Comment: And you can not hide them all by just removing that one new class?  Opposite issue is there is no easy way to just know what ones with the hidden class are visible. So you would have to loop over each one and determine that. Or if the class was there it is just a simple query.  Either way it works, just a personal preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are already using jQuery can simply do:

```js
function showhide(sent) {
  var $tgt = $('#' + sent).toggle()// toggles hide/show
  $(".classy").not($tgt).hide();// hide all but target
}
```

```css
.classy {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="click_thing" onclick="showhide('first_section')">
 Toggle section 1
</section>
<section  onclick="showhide('second_section')">
 Toggle section 2
</section>

<section id="first_section" class="classy">
  section one
</section>


<section id="second_section" class="classy">
  section two
</section>
```

Comment: Wonderful!  That worked perfectly!  I wasn't aware of the .not() functionality.  
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Look at your logic.

If it is `none`, you make it `inline-block`.

Then you *independently* test if it is `inline-block` (and if it was `none` then it will be now!) and set it to `none`.

You need an `else` in there.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you're saying about the logic flow.  I changed the second if to an else, but the issues remains.  It's odd too because the logic flow would seem to set the visibility always to none.  In this case it is setting it to inline-block but then cannot alter it after.
If I comment out the call setting the class display to none the function successfully toggles the visibility state even with the odd logic.
It's so strange.